# Bounds on gap between least eigenvalues of correlation matrix and its principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem is motivated from one of my research problems. If you can solve this before me, **I will include you as co-author in my work**.

Consider $\Sigma$, an $n \times n$ correlation matrix. Let $\lambda$ be the least eigenvalue of $\Sigma$. Consider $\Sigma_i'$, an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ principle minor of $\Sigma$ obtained by eliminating $i^{th}$ row and column. Let $\lambda_i'$ be the least eigenvalue of $\Sigma'$.

I am looking for an upper bound on the gap $\Delta = min_{i\in[1,n]}(\lambda_i' - \lambda)$. Empirically, I am observing that $\Delta$ is upper bounded by

1) $\Delta \leq $ the mean of the absolute values of all off-diagonal entries of $\Sigma$.

2) $\Delta \leq \frac{||C_{j}||}{n-1} \leq \frac{||C_{j}||_1}{n-1} \forall j \in [1,n]$, where $C_j$  denote a column vector of $\Sigma$ including all off-diagonal entries.

Note that 2) is a strictly tighter bound than 1).

**EDIT:** I made a few more strong empirical observations. If the weights in the eigenvector corresponding to least eigenvalue of $\Sigma$ are of same sign (+ve or -ve), then the above observations are true even for the signed entries of $\Sigma$. That is,

1)  $\Delta \leq -\alpha$, where $\alpha$ denote the mean of the values of all off-diagonal entries of $\Sigma$.
2) $\Delta \leq -\frac{\sum_{i=1,i \neq j}^{n}c_{ij}}{n-1}, \forall j \in [1,n]$, where $c_{ij}$ denotes the entry in $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column in $\Sigma$.

(The negative sign in both equations suggests that negative correlations promote stronger $\Delta$, which is strongly evident empirically.)

**END OF EDIT**

---

However, theoretically I have only managed to get looser upper bounds so far. Specifically, following is what I have at the moment:

i) $\Delta \leq ||C_j||\leq ||C_j||_1, \forall j \in [1,n]$, where $C_j$  is same as above.

ii) There exists $j \in [1,n]$, such that $\Delta \leq \frac{\||C_{j}||}{\sqrt{n-1}}$, where $C_j$ is same as above.

Any improvements to this or alternatively counter examples to empirical observations are most welcome and **will be acknowledged in my research**. In particular, if anyone can prove bullet ii) for all columns, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: How do your bounds compare to those produced by applying the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem)?

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you mean by the norms $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Comment: By ||v|| , I meant L2 norm of a vector v. The one with subscript '1' means L1 norm.
The bound obtained from interlacing theorem doesn't seem to be informative. Specifically, The second least eigenvalue of $\Sigma$ is upper bounded by $\frac{(n-\lambda)}{(n-1)}\leq\frac{n}{(n-1)}$, where $\lambda$ is the least eigenvalue of $\Sigma$. Hence, $\Delta≤ \frac{n}{n-1}$. 
On the other hand, we know that $\Delta$ could never exceed 1, because the least eigenvalues of any two correlation matrices could never exceed 1.

Comment: You might get a better response to this question on mathoverflow.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion. I will post it there as well.